# Accept good "retag" style edits?

Tags: discussion, tags, review

I recently gained access to review privileges, having just surpassed 2K reputation on SO.  I personally appreciated *good* retagging back where there was a distinct option for it.  Thus I am inclined to accept edits that provide a good retag (where that is the only content that needs editing.)  However, the move to eliminate that distinct option makes me wonder if I am violating the spirit of reviewing edits by accepting "retag" style edits.

Should I be accepting edits that *only* retag something as long as I feel the tag changes are worthwhile?

(It is difficult to find an answer to this question as there are no great matches via title searching, although I suspect it exists, buried in a long conversation under another title --  Hence this question with this title.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should approve edits that have "substantive improvements addressing multiple issues in the post."

If the tag edits by themselves make up a *substantive improvement* then approve them.  If they don't, then reject them as "too minor".  Of course if they're just wrong (removing tags that should be there or adding tags that aren't appropriate) then reject it as an invalid edit.

This is of course open to interpretation, so you do need to use your own judgement.  Certainly a question that has several highly inappropriate tags (i.e. major language tags for languages that don't apply to the question) rather than minor tags without a lot of subscribers, it's important to get rid of them.  Adding major tags that are very appropriate that were missing before can also be a substantial improvement to the post.  Edits on tags that are appropriate, but that are "secondary" tags that are going to have a fairly small effect on the visibility of the question should generally be made as a part of a comprehensive edit, and not made on its own.